# Error when running a bpel process in ode

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-plugin, bpel

I'm trying to learn to work with bpel. I choose Eclipse Bpel Designer and apache ode (on a tomcat server) in order to experiment. The process I tried to model was a loan process. It has 3 services: a creditRate service (written in eclipse bpel designer and deployed befo-hand an tested that it works), a [currency converter service](http://www.webservicex.net/ws/WSDetails.aspx?WSID=10&CATID=2), and the main orchestration process. While I had no errors on deployment when testing the web service from eclipse following errors occur:

> ERROR [ExternalService] Error sending message to Axis2 for ODE mex
>   {PartnerRoleMex#hqejbhcnphr87mcnd0np43 [PID
>   {CreditBuletinNamespace}CreditBuletin-137] calling
>   org.apache.ode.bpel.epr.WSAEndpoint@a64453.getRating(...) Status
>   REQUEST} org.apache.ode.axis2.OdeFault: Binding operation not found:
>   service {http://www.webserviceX.NET/}CurrencyConvertor port
>   CurrencyConvertorSoap name getRating.     at
>   org.apache.ode.axis2.util.SoapMessageConverter.createSoapRequest(SoapMessageConverter.java:154)

and

> Failure during invoke: Error sending message to Axis2 for ODE mex
>   {PartnerRoleMex#hqejbhcnphr87mcnd0np43 [PID
>   {CreditBuletinNamespace}CreditBuletin-137] calling
>   org.apache.ode.bpel.epr.WSAEndpoint@a64453.getRating(...) Status
>   REQUEST} 21:09:14,421 INFO  [BpelRuntimeContextImpl] ActivityRecovery:
>   Registering activity 19, failure reason: Error sending message to
>   Axis2 for ODE mex {PartnerRoleMex#hqejbhcnphr87mcnd0np43 [PID
>   {CreditBuletinNamespace}CreditBuletin-137] calling
>   org.apache.ode.bpel.epr.WSAEndpoint@a64453.getRating(...) Status
>   REQUEST} on channel 33

Can someone help me out with a solution? I have searched for some solution but have not found one that works. It may be that due to my poor knowledge I am not searching right or not doing something right. Because this description may be confusing I have attached my solution because I believe they will tell more of what I'm trying to do and how wrong I am doing it. http://www.mediafire.com/?9bjgt44spln1zwr

Thank-you in advance

EDIT: after doing an iterative approach (as sugested in the first answer)  it seems that the external conversion service was not responding from ode. This is strange because the service worked from the browser and no error was reported when deplying. Again because of my poor knowledge I believe code speaks better than my phrasing. I have made an eclipse project just with the external currency convertor. Any help / guidance is heartly appreciated. Thank you in advance. http://www.mediafire.com/?56csca1qgt5ka9a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CreditRating` process works fine, the error lies in the `CreditBuletin` process. When I test this one with soapUI, I get a `selectionFailure`. This error in BPEL tells you that something is wrong with a `from` or `to` in your process.

To outline the problem here is a very simplified version of the activities of your `CreditBuletin` process, reduced to just the initial `receive`, the final `reply` and one of your `assign` activities inbetween. You can paste this into the main `sequence` of your process to reproduce the problem.

```
<bpel:receive name="receiveInput" partnerLink="clientInput" operation="getLoan" portType="tns:CreditBuletinPT" variable="receiveInput" createInstance="yes"></bpel:receive>

        <bpel:assign validate="no" name="AssignFinal">
            <bpel:copy>
                <bpel:from>
                    <bpel:literal>
                        <tns:SumaRON xmlns:tns="CreditBuletinNamespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                            <output>0</output>
                        </tns:SumaRON>
                    </bpel:literal>
                </bpel:from>
                <bpel:to variable="outputResult" part="parameters"></bpel:to>
            </bpel:copy>
            <bpel:copy>
                <bpel:from>
                    <![CDATA[$loanWithInterest * bpel:getVariableData('CurrencyRateInputResponse','parameters','ConversionRateResult')]]>
                </bpel:from>
                <bpel:to part="parameters" variable="outputResult">
                    <bpel:query queryLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0">
                        <![CDATA[output]]>
                    </bpel:query>
                </bpel:to>
            </bpel:copy>
        </bpel:assign>

        <bpel:reply name="outputResult" partnerLink="clientInput" operation="getLoan" portType="tns:CreditBuletinPT" variable="outputResult"></bpel:reply>
```

You are trying to assign the same variable twice, first with a default initialization. This doesn't make much sense, but for some reason the BPEL editor generates these initializations on default. You get a correct reply, if you change the `from` statement in the second `copy` to something else, for instance

```
<![CDATA[bpel:getVariableData('receiveInput','parameters','suma')]]>
```

So, your problem(s) come(s) from your `from` statements, most likely the ones that use the `getVariableData()` function. Now, I don't want to repair all expressions in your process (because there are many and that is your task), but I suggest to have a look at all of them. Start with a minimal working process, such as the one above with the `from` exchanged and do incremental updates of functionality while testing each increment. That way, you will eventually end up with something that works.

Comment: Thanks so much for your advice. Turns out the currency convertor was not getting a response which is strange because when I invoke it from a browser is works. I have made a new project just with it but I can't tell if it's right because I haven't seen an example with calling an external web service from eclipse with ode. If it is not too much could you give me your expertise on this matter?. Thanks you in advance

Comment: It seems that the currency converter service does not work. When I call it from soapUI (or the Eclipse Web Services Explorer), I get a soap fault with the error: `System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.IO.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk.` and a stack trace. This is quite a dubious error message ;) Please note that even if there's a web page at that host you can access in your browser does not mean that their service is able to process requests.

Comment: The same happens when I try to invoke their global weather service. They really seem to have some trouble right now. If you need the currency converter service, you should probably contact them.